# Formatting node apps for AWS deployment

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to deploy a node.js app on aws EC2 Beanstalk. My problem is, I can't figure out how to move from my localhost testing environment to aws standard. Right now, my app works on port 8081 by using the following code.

```
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
})
```

How would I change this server variable to work on an actual domain?

Comment: I'm developping an node/Vuejs app and i planned to do my next deployment on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with PM2 (after some advices from sysadmins): http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/tutorials/use-pm2-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk/, hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your intent is to provide a public-facing web application, your code will work as is, albeit with a few caveats:

- Currently your server will listen on port 8081. Once deployed to AWS users would have to browse to www.somedomain.com:8081 to reach your application. (Assuming the host instance allows traffic on that port. See below).
- If your intent is to have users reach your application at www.somedomain.com - *without specifying a port* - you'll want the server to listen on port 80 instead.

  `var server = app.listen(80, function () { ... }`

In either case you'll need to ensure that the security group rules for the EC2 host instance allow incoming TCP traffic on the listening port. Likewise, if your EC2 host instance is behind a load balancer you'll need to allow incoming traffic on the appropriate ports there as well.

For something a little fancier, you can try deploying your application to Elastic Beanstalk using Docker and exposing port 8081 in the dockerfile. This way users would still reach it at www.somedomain.com (via http port 80) and you could continue to develop and test locally using port 8081.

One final note: you didn't provide much information about what your application is or how you intend to use it, so I'm making quite a few assumptions based only on the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

This code works great for me with node on Elastic Beanstalk, and allows me to seamlessly switch between localhost and remote development without changing any code:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8081;

var server = app.listen(port, function () {
    //server is started!!!
})
```